# How can I require a html template with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to require a html template in the script and then run browserify from the CLI.

Say I want to grab a template and append it to the body.

```
//index.js

var template = require('./template.html');
document.body.appendChild(template);
```

and

```
<!-- template.html -->
<p>Woooo!</p>
```

Then using the CLI to wrap it all up in Browserify.

`browserify index.js > build.js`

When loading an index.html template in the browser that references `build.js` I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

which is referencing

```
....

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
<div class="slide">
    <h2 data-slide-title></h2>
    <div data-slide-copy></div>
</div>
},{}]},{},[1])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use: https://github.com/substack/brfs

1

`npm install brfs`

2

```
var fs = require('fs');
var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/robot.html', 'utf8');
console.log(html);
```

3

```
browserify -t brfs example/main.js > bundle.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Good option is [jstify](https://github.com/zertosh/jstify).

```
browserify ./app/main.js -t jstify > static/bundle.js
```

For more information take a look this [link](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=5NPGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=So%20far,%20you%E2%80%99ve%20only%20used%20embedded%20view%20templates%20in%20the%20code%20base%20for%20Munich%20Cinema.However,%20Backbone%20pr&source=bl&ots=tx2fd_H04c&sig=dzrQEjyum5WBeG4Fr_CQdN2KQSg&hl=uk&sa=X&ei=UmBOVISnMInMyAOYv4DQDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=So%20far%2C%20you%E2%80%99ve%20only%20used%20embedded%20view%20templates%20in%20the%20code%20base%20for%20Munich%20Cinema.However%2C%20Backbone%20pr&f=false)