# Unable to import '.vue' file as template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, browserify, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to import a `.vue` file as my HTML template in a Vue component (with vueify as part of the build process). I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: invalid template option:function VueComponent(options) {
      this._init(options);
    } 
(found in <TestComponent>)
```

**`index.ts`**

```
declare var window: Window;
import TestComponent from "./components/test/Test";

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  let testComponent = Vue.component("test-component", TestComponent);

  let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
      testComponent: testComponent
    }
  });
});
```

**`components/test/test.ts`**

```
declare var Vue: typeof Function;
declare var VueClassComponent: any;

@VueClassComponent.default({
  // template: "<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>",
  template: require("./Test.vue"),
  props: {
    name: String
  }
})
export default class TestComponent extends Vue {
  name: "Test";
  message: String = "";
  mounted(): void {
    this.message = "Hello " + this.name;
  }
}
```

**`components/test/Test.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h5>Here is your message: {{ message }}</h5>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./test.ts" lang="ts"></script>
```

**`index.html`**

```
<html><body>
  <div id="app">
    <test-component></test-component>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/vue-class-component/dist/vue-class-component.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/app.js"></script> 
</body></html>
```

For the build I've got three files:

**`vue.config.js`**

```
var ts = require("typescript");
module.exports = {
  customCompilers: {
    ts: function (content , cb){
      var result = ts.transpileModule(content , {
          compilerOptions: {
            module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS
          }
        });
      cb(null , result.outputText)
    }
  }
}
```

**`build.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
tsc &&
browserify -t vueify -e build/app.js -o res/js/app.js
```

**`tsconfig.json`**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es5",
        "es2015.promise"
    ]
},
"include": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

When I change the `template` property in the `components/test/test.ts` file to a string (as the commented out example). The page renders fine, it's only when trying to use the `.vue` file that I encounter this issue. I've searched extensively for similar issues but it's very hard to find concise examples which use my specific combination of `browserify`, `typescript`, `vue-class-component` and stand-alone modules with the `.vue` file and `.js` separate.

Comment: You could either move everything into the vue-file and in the script tag place your TS. Or change the .vue File to an .html file and require it that way

Comment: @GOB - when I change the extension to `.html` I get an error when running the `build.sh`: `test.html:1
<template>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276019/how-can-i-require-a-html-template-with-browserify